# Rails 5 ui-icons.png file in /assets/images not served by Rails 5?

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-5, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using Rails 5 with AngularJS and Bootstrap.

I have a directive that generates a form which uses an icon  I am getting from ui-icons_444444_25x240.png.

This file is located in app/assets/images, but the system seems to be unable to find it.  I get the following error in the console:

```
angular-animate.self-4159531cc5685b66e6cdfd76c35d196124b4dde2fa449ceca973e3af2b070f66.js?body=1:766 GET http://localhost:3000/assets/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is the directive that is looking for the icons:

```
function templateConstantsModal(projectName) {
let buttonCaption = "OK";
return `<div class="modal-header"> 
  <h5 class="modal-title bold" id="modal-title">Budget Constants for ${projectName}</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

      <p class="italic" ng-if="$ctrl.list.length == 0">Click <strong>Add New</strong> to add a budget constant</p>

     <div class="container col-sm-12" ng-if="$ctrl.list.length>0">
       <div class="row bold">
         <div class="col-sm-5">Constant</div>
         <div class="col-sm-5">Value</div>
         <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
       </div>

       <div class="row"  ng-repeat="obj in $ctrl.list">
         <div class="col-sm-5">{{obj.name}}</div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">{{obj.value}}</div>
         <div class="col-sm-3"> 
         <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" ng-click=$ctrl.edit(obj.name)></span>
           <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close" ng-click=$ctrl.delete(obj.name) ></span>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>

  </div>
  <div class="center">__________________________</div>
  <div class = "modal-footer" id="modal-footer">

      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.addNew()">Add new</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
  </div>`;
```

}

The network pane of the Chrome developer tools seems to show the file not found on my local machine, but it is clearly there.  I've put copies of an image folder with this .png file in other directories (same directory as the script, public/images etc. but it doesn't seem to be looking there.

The only odd thing I see in the network panel of google dev tools is that the filetyhpe of this .png file is marked "text/html" for some reason, although the file name itself is correct, and the file has the correct image content.

[image: Developer Pane]

Heres the file tree from the root:

[image]

Code that uses the icon:

```
      <div class="col-sm-3"> 
         <span class="ui-icon u**i-icon-pencil"** ng-click=$ctrl.edit(obj.name)></span>
           <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close" ng-click=$ctrl.delete(obj.name) ></span>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the way it's supposed to be done, but I was able to solve this problem by a) creating a subdirectory assets/stylesheets/images and   putting the file ui-icons_444444_246x240.png inside, and then modificyling application.css to include the directive

```
*= require_directory ./images
```

Seems like kind of a hack, but at least it works.

If anybody knows how this is supposed to be done, please advise.